# How to make a header with a binary matrix code as background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, header-footer

I try to generate with tikz a header for each page with a binary matrix code.
as:

[image]

currently my working code

```
\RequirePackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=Black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3cm);
  \foreach \x in {0.0,2.0, ..., 25.0}{\foreach \y in {1, ..., 4.0} \node[draw=none,color=green] at (\x,\y) {\tiny A};};
  \foreach \x in {1.0,3.0, ..., 25.0}{\foreach \y in {1, ..., 4.0}  \node[draw=none,color=cyan] at (\x,\y) {\tiny T};};
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,fill=MidnightBlue]
        {\color{white}\partlabel#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
```

\end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

current result:
[image: result]

**Edit:** Finally I found a conrrect way to display matrix of 1 and 0.
I need to found how to randomize the number to print and when is 0 set white color ant 1 green colors.
I updated the code not the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the `random` function:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{Random0}{white}
\colorlet{Random1}{green}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)},yshift=-3cm]
        \path[fill=Black] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,3cm);
        \foreach \x in {0,1, ..., 70}{
          \foreach \y in {0, ...,7} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Random{random(0,1)}
            \node[draw=none,color=Random\Random,anchor=south west,font=\tiny,xshift=-.05cm] 
              at (\x*.3cm,\y*.33cm) 
              {\Random};};
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For fun, here is a solution in ConTeXt. Some remarks:

1. I use `OCR-A` font to match the font used in the movie.
2. I use three shades of green. Colors are defined in the `HSV` colorspace and the three colors just have different saturation values.
3. I use a `TABLE` for typesetting for ease of use. One could have used a simple `\halign` as well.
4. For ConTeXt users, this code also shows how to use the `interfaces.definecommand` function to define macros at the lua end.

```
\definecolor[green]      [h=120,s=1,v=0.75]
\definecolor[darkgreen]  [h=120,s=1,v=0.5]
\definecolor[brightgreen][h=120,s=1,v=1]

\startsetups matrix
  \setupTABLE[style={\definedfont[name:ocraextended]}, background=color, backgroundcolor=black]
  \setupTABLE[frame=off, offset=none]
\stopsetups

\setupbodyfont[dejavu]

\startluacode
  local colors = { "green", "darkgreen", "brightgreen" }
  local showNumber = function()
    local color  = math.random(3)
    local number = math.random(2) - 1
    context.style({color=colors[color]}, number)
  end

  local printMatrix = function(rows,cols)
    context.bTABLE{setups="matrix"}
      for i = 1,cols do
        context.bTR()
        for j = 1,rows do
          context.bTD()
            showNumber() 
          context.eTD()
        end
        context.eTR()
      end
    context.eTABLE()
  end

  interfaces.definecommand {
    name = "printMatrix",
    arguments = {
      { "option", "number" },
      { "option", "number" },
    },
    macro = printMatrix,
  }
\stopluacode

\starttext

\startTEXpage[offset=1mm]
\printMatrix[40][40]
\stopTEXpage

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]